# How to use OrderBy in Laravel using eloquent relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two model: Category and PostAd model.
They two have relation with each other.
In laravel view i have passed data through Category Model to display PostAd data.
I want to apply OrderBy condition in query but it doesn't work

***Code***

```
$data['category'] = Category::with(['postads'])->where('id',$id)->get();
```

I want to do this

```
$data['category'] = Category::with(['postads'])->where('id',$id)->orderBy('adtitle','DESC')->get();
```

But it doesn't work because it is Category Model.
How can i solve this.

Comment: Show us the relationship function between these 2 models.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to get PostAd data with an order by then you can do an eager load Order by.

And here you're using `get()` method so it should be `first();` because `->where('id',$id)` always get one record.

```
$data['category'] = Category::with(['postads' => function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('adtitle', 'DESC');
    }])->where('id',$id)->first();
```

Comment: Select the answer if helped.